# NodeJS AWS Lambda Serverless Proxy get by parameter - amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I am trying to do a request to a lambda with serverless express proxy app. I build express app with amplify CLI and selected CRUD operations for lambda.

Besides tons of generated code i get this line:

```
const hashKeyPath = '/:' + partitionKeyName;
```

which is then added to a url of the `app.get` like this:

```
app.get(path + hashKeyPath, function (req, res) {
  res.json({
    data: JSON.stringify(req.params),
    dekor: JSON.stringify(
      req.apiGateway.event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId
    ),
  });
```

now the problem is that my parameter is now prefixed with colon character `:` like this:
https://xxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/address/:eu-west-1:xxx-8718-42b9-b8b8-ce82e9d9e7a0
See this colon character between `/address/` and the value. I cannot get rid of it. If i remove colon character from `hashKeyPath` I get 404 when I try to call api gateway. But then againt I need the value of parameter to be without colon character I literally get this when I do `req.params`: `:eu-west-1:xxx-8718-42b9-b8b8-ce82e9d9e7a0` instead of `eu-west-1:xxx-8718-42b9-b8b8-ce82e9d9e7a0` which is required partition value in dynamoDB, but because of colon in front I do not get any values from dynamoDB. How could I resolve this, so path works without colon charater for hashKeyPath?

Comment: What happens if you remove the colon in `const hashKeyPath = '/:' + partitionKeyName;`?

Comment: Api throws 404.